# VariableSizedWrapGrid within GroupStyle events not firing

Tags: c#, gridview, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Ok, this is driving me nuts! I have spent a good half of my day working on this problem. I am using a XAML based Windows 8.1 app, and essentially I am trying to implement some drag and drop functionality between groups in a GridView. So far everything has been working, except when I try to "drop" an item into a new group. After way to much time, I have narrowed it down to the "drop" event not being fired for the GroupStyle.Panel VariableSizedWrapGrid. I was trying to follow something along the lines of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/07/16/drag-and-drop-within-a-grouped-grid-view.aspx) webpage.

I for the life of me cannot figure out why it won't fire. I have tried testing other drop events throughout my gridview, and they all seem to be working as expected.

Below is the code I currently have in place:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        CanDragItems="True"
        DragItemsStarting="itemGridView_DragItemsStarting"
        IsSwipeEnabled="true"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="splash"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name }" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,70,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False">
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                            <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}"
                                    Click="Button_Click">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,-11,10,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-11,0,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Drop="VariableSizedWrapGrid_Drop" AllowDrop="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

I really hope someone out there can see my error! I'm sure it is something simple, but I just need someone to point out the obvious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, then found this example:
[How to drag item between groups in grouped gridview](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-drag-item-between-c66cc4d2)

I tried to use StackPanel as ItemsPanel of GridView, worked for me. Try to use StackPanel instead of ItemsWrapGrid for your GridView.

```
 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Still can't understand this behavior, any ideas?

Comment: I will definitely give this a go tonight. I'm just glad I am not the only one with this issue!